# program that fully documents every file on drive

Tags: python, file, windows

I have a program which goes through your drive and does two things:

1. For every file extension it creates a file "file of extension_name" and whenever it encounters a file with that extension, it writes the path of it to its appropriate file.
2. Once it finishes going through every file, it goes through every file created in step 1 and counts all of the files in it, and writes to a *new* file the number of files to that extension.

NOTE: I do not follow any variable naming conventions, I exclusively use camelCase. If that is unsatisfactory, let me know...

NOTE: The runtime of the program depends upon how many files you have in your drive...

NOTE: Sorry I didn't really document the second half of my code that well...

NOTE: Most of the try-except blocks came from a bunch of errors I kept getting while trying to access certain files...

```
import os
import time


def documentFile(path):
    global numberOfFilesChecked
    for r in range(len(path) - 1, -1, -1):  # search from the back to the front of
        # the file name for the period which marks the extension.
        if path[r] == ".":
            try:
                fObject = open(f"file of   {path[r + 1:]}.txt", "a+")
                # we create a file named "file of  extension", and we set it to append
                # mode
                numberOfFilesChecked += 1
                fObject.write(path + "\n")
                # we then write the name of the file being indexed to the file we just opened, then add a line break.
                fObject.close()
                if numberOfFilesChecked % 5000 == 0:
                    print(numberOfFilesChecked)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
            break


def loopThroughDir(path):
    try:
        for iterator in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.isdir(path + "\\" + iterator):  # if the path is a folder
                loopThroughDir(path + "\\" + iterator)
            else:  # if it's a regular file
                if iterator[0:4] != "fileO":
                    documentFile(path + "\\" + iterator)
    except PermissionError:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    documentationStrings = []
    extension = None
    cTime = (int(time.time()) / 3600)
    os.makedirs(f"C:\\fileDocumentation\\{cTime}")
    os.chdir(f"C:\\fileDocumentation\\{cTime}")
    numberOfFilesChecked = 0
    loopThroughDir("C:\\")
    print(int(time.time())/3600 - int(cTime))
    print(numberOfFilesChecked)
    numberOfFileTypes = 0
    listOfFilesInCTime = os.listdir(f"C:\\fileDocumentation\\{cTime}")
    aFile = open("controlFile.txt", "a+")
    for fileContainingExtensions in listOfFilesInCTime:
        numberOfFileTypes += 1
        extension = None
        fileExtensionFile = open(f"C:\\fileDocumentation\\{cTime}\\" + fileContainingExtensions)
        numberOfFilesCheckedInEachExtension = 0
        for eachLine in fileExtensionFile:
            for x in range(len(eachLine) - 1, -1, -1):  # search from the back to the front of
                # the file name for the period which marks the extension.
                if eachLine[x] == ".":
                    extension = eachLine[x:]
                    # because there is a \n at the end of the line we remove it.
                    extension.strip("\n")
                    break
            numberOfFilesCheckedInEachExtension += 1
        extension.strip("\n")
        documentationStrings.append([numberOfFilesCheckedInEachExtension, f"{numberOfFilesCheckedInEachExtension}"
                                                                          f" is the number of {extension}'s in the "
                                                                          f"file "
                                                                          f"which is {(numberOfFilesCheckedInEachExtension / numberOfFilesChecked) * 100}% "
                                                                          f"percent of the total {numberOfFilesChecked}.\n"])
    documentationStrings.sort()
    documentationStrings.reverse()
    for i in documentationStrings:
        aFile.write(i[1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PEP-8

Python introduced a coding convention almost 20 years ago, [namely PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Quoting certain section from the same:

> [...] The guidelines provided here are intended to improve the
> readability of code and make it consistent across the wide spectrum of
> Python code. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline:
>
> 1. When applying the guideline would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows this PEP.
> 2. To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean
>    up someone else's mess (in true XP style).
> 3. Because the code in question predates the introduction of the guideline and there is no other reason to be modifying that code.
> 4. When the code needs to remain compatible with older versions of Python that don't support the feature recommended by the style guide.

I do not think any of these 4 apply in your case, so it is better to follow convention for one-off scripts (and put it into habit). The most common ones being:

1. variables and functions follow `lower_snake_case` naming
2. constants follow `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`
3. classes are `UpperCamelCase`

### Functions

You start off with declaring 2 functions, then everything else is a mess of code all put inside the `if __name__` clause. Split this further into functions.

### os.path vs pathlib

Since you're using python 3.x, may I suggest looking into a more friendlier inbuilt module for path traversals, [called `pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). The docs provide few examples on how to easily convert your current code utilizing `os.path` and friends with their equivalent `pathlib` calls.

### File contexts

Python also has a context based file handling. You currently are opening the files explicitly, without ever calling a `.close()`. Prefer using the following syntax when operating with files:

```
with open("path/to/file", "mode") as fp:
    fp.write(something)
    # something_else = fp.read()
```

### Comments vs docstrings

Use docstrings instead of comments when describing what a function does. The spec can be found [on PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

---

PS: A lot of your code appears to be doing unnecessary work due to usage of string operations, instead of proper inbuilt methods. Few examples:

1. iterating over path string character by character to get extension instead of using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) (pathlib has similar functions)
2. generating path yourself, instead of having a glob based iteration over directory tree
3. stripping `\n` from extension, but not really overwriting the variable itself (`extension.strip("\n")`)